# How to refer/make use of dynamic id generated by Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

Here is my model:

```
(domain)-[:has]-(data_file)-[:contains]-(entities)-[:have]-(columns)-[:have]-(datatypes)
```

Code to import data

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from "file:///test.csv" as row
MERGE(domain:Domain{name:row.Domain})
MERGE(data_file:SourceFile{name:row.data_File})
MERGE(entity:Entity{name:row.Entity})
MERGE(column:ColumnName{name:row.Column_Name, Data_Type: row.Data_Type})
MERGE (domain)-[:HAS]->(data_file)
MERGE (data_file)-[:HAS]->(entity)
MERGE (entity)-[:HAS]->(column)
```

The problem I have now is that when two different entity nodes have same Column_Name but with different data types, both entity nodes points to a single node (matched by its Column_Name)

e.g

```
1. data_file-A has Entity-A, Column_Name: user_id (Data_Type: String)
2. data_file-B has Entity-B, Column_Name: user_id (Data_Type: Boolean)
```

When I run the import above, I expected that (1.) above should have an edge to node user_id whose data type is String, and (2.) should have another edge to another node user_id whose data type is Boolean.  But this is not happening. Both point to a single node whose name is `user_id`

How can I resolve this?  Is there a way to refer to the dynamic id created by neo4j while creating edges, so that I can create edges between those dynamic ids?

Something like `MERGE (entity.id)-[:HAS]->(column.id)`

Comment: Do you have some constraints (specially on `Column_Name`) ? Can you give them by typing `:schema` into the browser ?

Comment: @logisima There are no constraints.  I am simply reading a text file that has above structure to visualize details about domains, entities, fields etc.

Comment: This is strange, as your MERGE with both properties should match to the correct node (I'd only expect to see your behavior if the :ColumnName was being merged with only the `name` property). Which version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: I guess I am at fault here.  Thinking back on what MERGE does, I should have used CREATE instead of MERGE. Because MERGE is like an UPSERT.